# Mysql Database adding an integer to ascii

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, recursive-query

[image]

Hello everyone, so i wanted to convert a string into ascii code, i had to split it into char and convert each char into ascii and then merge them at the end. I want to add some constant value to each of the ascii characters before merging them back together. Can someone help how am i supposed to do that? Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the computation within `group_concat()`:

```
set @word = 'hello';

with recursive cte as (
    select @word as word, left(@word, 1) as val, 1 as idx
    union all
    select word, substring(word, idx + 1, 1), idx + 1 
    from cte 
    where idx < char_length(word)
)
select group_concat(ascii(val) + @add order by idx separator '') ascii_word from cte
```

Comment: Congratulations on the 100k.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff! Let me take the opportunity to congratulate you for reaching #2 all-time rep few weeks ago. Sky (or, if I may say, Skeet) is the limit for you now... Maybe 1 more year of hard work and you'll get there!